# How to compare data enter from jTextfield with Mongo database data through Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

Since i want to Compare the userId and password enter by the user in jTextFields  with the value of userid and password  present in my document  of mongodb,document in Mongodb is like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("500ee83ca5d4c30481aa2a13"),
 "User ID" : 10, 
 "Password" : "4554gf",}
```

Below code is on my `Login` button

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int s1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()); //number entering in jtextfield 
    String s2 = jPasswordField1.getText(); //password enter by user  
    if(s1== UserId  &&  s2==password) {
        this.dispose();//this will dispose the login gui
        a.setVisible(true);//this will visible the nxt gui
    }
    else {
        asd.setText("invalid user"); // label that shows if userid and dont match
    }
```

So its not working , so please tell how to do it ? i Hope you all understand my question

Comment: Please make your question clearer.  What exactly is not working?  Is your program always saying 'invalid user'?  Or is an exception occurring?  Where is `UserId` and `password` getting its values from?

Comment: @prunge i post answer of my question below !! `UserId` and `password` gettting values from user through text fields and comparing these values with data present in collection . i hope you get it

Answer (score 2):

**NEVER** use == to compare objects

Always use `equals()`

== will only work if they are the same object (same reference), with objects of same value but created differently it won't work.

Comment: i know to use `equals()`for objects but it was still not comparing, here above i wrote `==` accidently

Comment: @ SJuan76 Sorry for unclear question ! now i done it ...actully i was unable to retreive the values from mongodatabase and compare it with the values enter from the user ! now i am clear what to do.. ! thanks for looking into.

Answer (score 0):

That the way i done it:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    BasicDBObject view = new BasicDBObject();
    double id = 0;
    String pass = "";


    int s1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    String s2 = jPasswordField1.getText();
    view.put("Pateint ID", s1);
    DBCursor cur1 = Patient.coll.find(view);// cheeks in collection of specific id
    if (cur1.hasNext()) {
        DBObject o = cur1.next();//
        pass = (String) o.get("Password");//get password from mongodb
        id = (double) o.get("Pateint ID");// get pateintID from mongodb
    }

    if (s1 == id && s2.equals(pass))// matches id and password here 
   {
        this.dispose();


        a.setVisible(true);

    } else {
        asd.setText("invalid user");
    }

}
```